# how to progress bar based on count entered in field using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a simple form has two field with ids = "q9" , "q10" and one button named post , i put total number in "#q9", I am trying to code a progress bar that will be updated based on the count entered in "#q10" when user click post button. https://jsfiddle.net/v756hkd2/10/

```
  //jquery Code
    $(document).ready(function(){
     $(".postbtn").click(function(){
      var curStatus = $('#q9 input').val();;
      var startCount = $('#q10 input').val();
      $("#q9 input").change(function(){
      var progress = (curStatus / startCount) * 100;
      $("#myBar").width(progress);
  });
 });
});
```

Comment: first `$("#q9 input")` should be `$("input#q9")` input with id q9..change is not needed in inside click event

Comment: user will click ".postbtn" only one time to begin the process,  then the value in q9 will change automatically. For this i put change function to q9

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the problem is that you use change event listener in the click event listener.
Code is waiting for the #q9 input to change, but I guess you have already set it and you just need to use it.

Maybe something like this would work?

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".postbtn").on('click', function() {
        var progress = ($('#q9').val() / $('#q10').val()) * 100;
        $("#myBar").width(progress);
    });
});
```

EDIT:
I am not sure if I understood correctly. But it seemed like you fill change the #q9 input value automatically after post.
So I made a solution based on that this input value will change automatically and the change event will occur.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".postbtn").on('click', function() {
         // this is because after click the first label would appear
         var currentCount = $('#q9').val();
         var progress = (currentCount / $('#q10').val()) * 100;
         $("#myBar").width(progress + '%');
         $("#label").text(progress + '%');
         // then you start to listen the change of the current count input
         $('#q9').on('change', function(e) {
              currentCount = $(e.target).val();
              progress = (currentCount / $('#q10').val()) * 100;
              // and change it accordingly
              $("#myBar").width(progress + '%');
              $("#label").text(progress + '%');
         });
    }); 
});
```

A few notes:

1) $('#q9 input') won't work because it thinks that element with id #q9 has a child input, so I used $('#q9'), or you can use, like someone noted $('input#q9')

2) You can also use methods .change or .click. I just prefer using .on. :)

EDIT: I changed a bit the solution again. And added jsfiddle. It should work now - https://jsfiddle.net/v756hkd2/11/

And more beautiful code would be

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".postbtn").on('click', function() {
         // this is because after click the first label would appear
         changePercentage($('#q9').val());

         // then you start to listen the change of the current count input
         $('#q9').on('change', function(e) {
              changePercentage($(e.target).val());
         });
    }); 
    // then there won't be repeated code ;)
    function changePercentage(currentCount) {
        var progress = (currentCount / $('#q10').val()) * 100;
        $("#myBar").width(progress + '%');
        $("#label").text(progress + '%');
    }
});
```

Comment: Uuser will click ".postbtn" only one time to begin the process, then the value in q9 will change automatically. For this i have to put change function to q9.

Comment: I am sorry, I don't understand the user case completely. How will it change automatically? You have total and current count, user will put some values in it and then press post? Right? So the label % is based on the total and current count. Do you mean that after that it will go gradually  automatically from current count to the 100% ?

Comment: user will click post , it will run process in database , this process will push value in q9. and label %  will be based on the total and current count, then  it will go gradually automatically from current count to the 100%

Comment: this value pushed in q9 will be changed repeatedly till the progress reach 100%

Comment: I hope I understood correctly this time. I edited my answer accordingly.

Comment: EDIT: I changed a bit the solution again. And added jsfiddle. It chould work now - https://jsfiddle.net/v756hkd2/11/

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to listen to input's change event, if you want to update progress when pressing Post button. It's easier to listen to Post button click. Also values inside inputs are strings, so you have to convert them to numbers before calculation.

```
function getInputValue(selector) {
  var str = $(selector).val();
  return parseInt(str, 10);
}

function updateProgress() {
  var total = getInputValue('#q10');
  var current = getInputValue('#q9');
  var progress = (current / total) * 100;

  //if you want to limit number of digits after decimal point
  //progress = progress.toFixed(2);

  $("#myBar").css("width", progress + "%");
  $("#label").text(progress + "%");
}

$(function() {
  $(".postbtn").click(updateProgress);
  updateProgress();//if you want to render outside of click handler, for example after page load.
});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/yevt/ne1k7w03/2/